# Why does the existance of this void pointer cause Malloc to crash?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, void, libxml2

I have the following small, incomplete program, that attemps to parse in data from XML files.  The nature of some of this data will be unknown ahead of time, so I incorporated some of these void pointers into a struct.  When I run the program as it is here, I get some strange runtime errors.

You may well notice some bugs in my linked list; I'm not asking you to debug it (though if it bothers you feel free.  I'm beseeching someone to tell me why this crashes.  I am so ignorant of the cause I am frankly afraid to continue debugging it any further until this is explained.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <libxml/xmlreader.h>

typedef struct attributes{
  xmlChar *name;
  void *data;
  struct attributes *next;
};

typedef struct entity{
   char *reference;
   void *data; 
   struct attributes *my_attribs;
   struct entity *next;
};

typedef struct world_list{
   void *data; 
   struct entity *entity_list;
   struct world_list *next;
};

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
        xmlDocPtr doc;
    xmlNodePtr cur;
    printf("---WARNING---\n Weird things will happen to your world if you do not use a properly formatted XML document with NO SPACES (tabs only) in between texts!  \n\nThis may be fixed in future versions.\n---WARNING---\n\n");
    getchar();
    xmlNodePtr iterate;
    doc = xmlParseFile("./simple2.xml");
    if (doc== NULL) {
      printf("Document not parsed");
      return 1;
    }
    cur = xmlDocGetRootElement(doc);

    if (cur == NULL) {
      fprintf(stderr,"empty document\n");
      xmlFreeDoc(doc);
      return 2;
    }

    //cur->name: The node that we are in.

    if (xmlStrcmp(cur->name, (const xmlChar *) "world")) {
      fprintf(stderr,"document of the wrong type, root node != story");
      xmlFreeDoc(doc);
      return 3;
    }

    printf("cur->name: %s\n",cur->name);
    iterate=cur->children;
    //iterate=iterate->children;
    if (iterate==NULL) {
      printf("what the hell");
    }

    xmlNodePtr contents;


    struct world_list world; //This line of code creates the world.
    struct entity *entity_list;
    struct entity *entity_current;
    entity_list=NULL;
    struct attributes *attribute_list=NULL;
    //world.entity_list=entity_list;
    while (iterate!=NULL){
     //  if (xmlStrcmp(iterate->name, (const xmlChar *) "object")){
          xmlChar *key;
          key = xmlNodeListGetString(doc, iterate->xmlChildrenNode, 1);
          if (key==NULL) {xmlFree(key);iterate=iterate->next;continue;}
        printf("|name: %s, getstring: %s|\n",iterate->name,key);
        xmlFree(key);

          if (!xmlStrcmp(iterate->name, (const xmlChar *) "object")) { //WHY does this need to be inverted !?!?

        if (entity_list == NULL){
            printf("entity_list initilized start");
            entity_list=malloc(sizeof(entity_list));
            printf("entity_list initilized done");
            entity_list->next=NULL;
            entity_current=entity_list;
          } else
          {
            printf("list NOT init");
            entity_current->next=malloc(sizeof(entity_list));
            entity_current=entity_current->next;
          }

        contents=iterate->children;
        xmlChar *key2;


        while (contents != NULL) {
          key2 = xmlNodeListGetString(doc, contents->xmlChildrenNode, 1);
          if (key2==NULL) {xmlFree(key2);contents=contents->next;continue;}



          if (attribute_list==NULL) {
            entity_current->my_attribs = malloc(sizeof(attribute_list));
            attribute_list = entity_current->my_attribs;
          } else {
            attribute_list->next = malloc(sizeof(attribute_list));
            attribute_list=attribute_list->next;
          }
          attribute_list->name=malloc(sizeof(xmlChar)*xmlStrlen(key2));
          printf("the key being added is %s", key2);
          *attribute_list->name = *key2;
          attribute_list->next=NULL;
          entity_current->next=NULL;
          printf("Subchild: |name: %s, getstring: %s|\n",contents->name,key2);
          xmlFree(key2);
          contents=contents->next;
        }
        attribute_list=NULL; //If you don't do this the attributes of one object will be added on the list of another object's attributes; good luck with that.

          }
      iterate=iterate->next;
    }
    //entity_current->next=NULL; 
    entity_current=entity_list;

    if (entity_current == NULL) {printf("uh-oh."); return 4;}
    int track=0;
    while (entity_current!= NULL){
       printf("Properties for: %i\n",track++);
       printf("-------\n");
       attribute_list=entity_current->my_attribs;
       while (attribute_list != NULL) {
         printf("item %s\n",attribute_list->name);
         attribute_list=attribute_list->next;
       }
       printf("-------\n");
        entity_current=entity_current->next;
    }

    //Keep iterating EVERY OTHER ->next will be "text"
    //Regardless of whether or not you are in "child mode"

    return 0;
}
```

I get the following error:

```
     Error in `./statact': malloc(): memory corruption (fast): 0x000000000068eda0 
entity_list initilized startentity_list initilized doneAborted
```

(You'll notice the printfs here.)

However, something is curious.  I found that by merely commenting out the lines of code that define the void pointers in the struct.....**the program does not crash.**

There is another way to make it execute without crashing: the if-else block that starts with the line `if (entity_list == NULL){` can be moved below the start of the loop which is *immediately* below it `while (contents != NULL) {` and it seems to run without crashing as well (though with my current intentions it more or less amounts to a logical error to do so.)

The other information I have is:
-Debian Stable
-When my program starts, it prints to console message `./statact: /usr/local/lib/libxml2.so.2: no version information available (required by ./statact)`

I would really appreciate any clarification on this, because I'm fairly well foggy on this one.  Thanks.

Comment: Run it under `valgrind`. But likely those bugs you haven't fixed are what's doing it.

Comment: `entity_list=malloc(sizeof(entity_list));` - Do you want to allocate size of a pointer or size of a struct ?

Comment: The description "commenting out the lines of code that define the void pointers in the struct" does not make sense.   If you mean you comment out the declarations of struct members ....    if commenting out seemingly unrelated code stops an error from manifesting, then that's a common symptom that some OTHER code is doing something wrong  (all the commented lines do is affect how code and data is organised in your program and therefore changes what is tromped by code that does something wrong).    In any event, there is too much code here.  You need to do some work to provide an [mcve].

Comment: @peter What I mean is that since none of the code ever references the void pointers inside the struct, I tried commenting them out and... it was stable, interestingly enough (if that's what your getting at?)  Also, I suppose I could trim the error handling  but since the linked lists are mated with the XML I'm honestly not sure where to start isolating it (I don't normally ask.) I'll read the link though.

Comment: @Elyasin I think you found the main problem!

Comment: @user1833028 - yes, that's what I mean.   If removing unreferenced members from a struct definition cause symptoms of an error to go away, that indicates some of your OTHER code is the cause.   The fact that the crash occurs inside `malloc()` does not mean the cause is in `malloc()`.

Comment: @Elaysin Whoops.

Comment: There are more problems. `*attribute_list->name = *key2` is one I have found with a cursory glance. Perhaps you should get a C textbook and do some basic exercises with strings and pointers.

Comment: Also enable warnings in your compiler and read them.

Comment: @n.m Do you reccomend anything in particular?

Comment: K & R is a great book really. Loved it.

Comment: in general, for flexibility, the definition of a struct should be kept separate from a `typedef` for that struct

Comment: strongly suggest honoring the right hand margin of a page. (typically either column 80 or column 72.)  That makes it much easier to display/read on a printed page and/or on the terminal

Comment: please consistently indent the code.  I.E. make all indent levels the same width (perfer 4 spaces).  Setting some indent levels at 2 spaces and some at 4 spaces makes the code much more difficult to read, understand, etc

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding, follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: (malloc, calloc, realloc), always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: regarding: *attribute_list->name = *key2; and `xmlFree(key2);` (and similar statements) you probably want to use strdup() otherwise, `attribute_list->name` will point to a location in the heap that the application does not own.  Any accessing of that location is undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: regarding: `if (key2==NULL)
                    {
                        xmlFree(key2);` why call `xmlFree()` when there is nothing to free?

Comment: K&R is a very good book indeed. You just have to bear in mind that it is not updated for the current standard so you need to make some minor adjustments (declare `main` with an explicit `int` type, don't use `gets`).

Comment: @Elaysin.. If you bother to make that an answer I'll accept it.